# How to get multiple stream input in Kurento OpenCv module?

Tags: kurento

I am working on getting multiple media streams to the openCv module in Kurento.
But I am not able to find out the way.
(In simpler term, I am looking for the Hub module with openCv capablities)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.